# pygraphviz - Install on Ubuntu 10 with django-extensions

Tags: ubuntu, python, django, graphviz

I'm trying to install *pygraphviz* under *Ubuntu 10.04* in order to use it within my *Django* projects.

I used *synaptic* and it was installed without any problem.

I also installed *django-extensions* with *synaptic* (*django-extensions* has a tool that uses *pygraphviz* and this is the one that I need)

Now when I try to use *django-extensions* with *pygraphviz*

```
$ python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o model.png
```

I'm getting an

> Error: need pygraphviz python module ( apt-get install
>   python-pygraphviz )

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script seems to be unable to find the `pygraphviz` module. To fix that, you should make sure that `pygraphviz` is in your Python's `sys.path`.

In case you find out the module is not installed, you have two *alternative* ways of installing it:

- `sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz` (as suggested by the error message),
- `sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev` and
  `sudo pip install pygraphviz --install-option='--include-path=/usr/include/graphviz' --install-option='--library-path=/usr/lib/graphviz'`
  This is the method I strongly recommend, which uses `pip`, the Python package installer.
  Specifying the options is required because otherwise the pygraphviz installer seems [unable to find the paths](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.4rc1/install.html#providing-path-to-graphviz).

Comment: `sudo pip install pygraphviz` fails because the `graphviz` package is a requirement. The only way to get this installed on Ubuntu in one go is with the first option: `sudo apt-get install python-pygraphviz` .

Comment: if you get a permissions error with `sudo pip install pygraphviz ...` you can do a  `pip install --user pygraphviz ...` instead